# TabLayout в Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

Как сделать TabLayout в фрагментах, что бы были такие подменюшки

[image: Нужно реализовать TabLayout в фрагментах]

Comment: Вопрос не понятен.Я правильно понимаю, что вы попробовали просто сделать такую разметку но у вас не получилось? Или вы спрашиваете о принципиально возможности? Если второе - то да, это возможно. В выдвижное меню можно поместить абсолютно любую разметку, ограничений нет никаких.

Comment: Да у меня не получается сделать такую разметку

Comment: Почему бы вам не показать разметку и не рассказать что именно не получилось?...

Comment: Разметку можно просто взять с шаблонов, главный вопрос как добавить его в фрагмент

Comment: Т.е. на самом деле ваш вопрос про то как разметку свою в фрагменте использовать вместо активити?

Comment: да, вы совершено правы. Имеется ввиду мб кто то делал и есть что то там на гихабе или код.

Comment: Эммм, нет, врятли вы такой пример где-то найдёте. Это нестандартный кейс и при этом максимально простой. Т.е. просто берётся фрагмент и в нём отображается разметка. Тут, вроде, нечего совершенно показывать.

Comment: Ну как сделать TabLayout в фрагменте?

Comment: Переопределить метод `onCreateView` во фрагменте и загрузить туда разметку. Далее, если хотите вложенные фрагменты надо юзать `getChildFragmentManager()`. По первой части вам подойдёт любой вводный урок по фрагментам. Вы всё ещё не пояснили в чём у вас конкретно проблема. Вы пробовали сами во фрагмент разметку поместить?

Comment: Я вот не понимаю, как переопределить метод "Переопределить метод onCreateView во фрагменте и загрузить туда разметку" то есть с чего начать? Мне создать шаблон TabLayout и его переопределить?

Comment: В ответ написал. Вам нужно просто взять любой из тысяч примеров в интернете и смотреть как там сделано. Нет никакого смысла сюда ещё раз повторять любой урок из сети

Comment: И да, когда вы станете во фрагментах фрагменты отображать - готовьтесь к неделям мучений с последующим отказом от фичи и/или перепиливании табов на вью вместо вложенных фрагментов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. вопрос на самом деле о том что такое фрагмент и как им пользоваться, то приведу просто код фрагмента с разметкой в него загружаемой

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```